# ffmpeg batch command to take stereo wav input file and create an output file that consists of that same file twice in parallel

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, batch-file

I have a bunch of stereo wav files and want to create new files from them where every output file contains the input stereo wav file as the first and - in parallel - also as the second audio stream, thus, creating 2x stereo wave files with identical, parallel stereo streams:

input files(1x stereo): stereo_1.wav, stereo_2.wav, stereo_3.wav, stereo_4.wav, etc.

output files (2x stereo): stereo_1_x2.wav, stereo_2_x2.wav, stereo_3_x2.wav, stereo_4_x2.wav, etc.

I tried various commands like
`-i "%~1" -map 0:a -map 0:a -ac 4 "%~n1 x2.wav"`, `-i "%~1" -filter_complex "[0:a][0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]"` (not sure what the `[a]` is for) or `-i "%~1" -i "%~1" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]"` but none of them created any output file.

Comment: I can't figure out what it is you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by 'parallel stereo streams'? Do you mean 4.0 audio in a single file? What is your use-case for this? I'm getting hints of [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: yes, I wanna create an output file containing 4 audio channels which are 2x the same stereo input file. Use case is to convert stereo impulse response wav file into true-stereo impulse response file for convolution reverb.

Comment: I'd reinvestigate exactly what the convolution process requires as input. I've never used one that needed two stereo files, let alone two that are identical yet artificially bolted together into a fake quad. That seems truly bizarre.

Comment: maybe this helps to understand the true-stereo convolution concept: [link](https://www.audiothing.net/effects/fog-convolver/)

Comment: I can't find a manual anywhere on there & their description for dropping to stereo is very confusing. They show a picture of 2 mono files being dropped but the advert copy says 2 stereo files [which honestly makes no sense if they're identical]. BTW, I've been working with convolution reverb since someone first tried to sell the idea to the company I worked for - in the late 1990's ;)

Comment: it might seem odd but when I render the same stereo impulse file into a single 4-channel wave file (essentially resulting in a L-R-L-R 4-channel config) and load such a file into the convolution plugin, it actually gives me true-stereo with an impressive spacial quality. So I'm looking for a way of doing the "merging" stuff via ffmpeg and a batch file instead of doing it manually for each impulse in the DAW. So my qestion is: What ffmpeg command would I need to get a 4-channel L-R-L-R output file from an L-R stereo input file?

Comment: What happens if you spit the stereo to two mono, L/R files? With no manual for the software I'm guessing, but my guess is you're doing something wrong to need to do it that way.

Comment: I need to get from L-R input to L-R-R-L file structure for true-stereo impulses. Please see first answer discussion below.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you have a link to the manual, I'd be happy to read it to check the workflow. I still think you have some misconception, somewhere.

Comment: I'm not aware of any manual. I actually just checked some commercial true-stereo files and they have a mirrored L-R-R-L channel layout (although L-R-L-R gives good-sounding results, too). So this is what I need to get from an L-R input file. I already know how to split L-R files.

Comment: Links to example files?

Comment: Steinberg reference: [link](https://steinberg.help/cubase_plugin_reference/v9/en/_shared/topics/plug_ref/reverence/reverence_true_stereo_r.html)

Comment: Ah, OK. So you did misunderstand it, but not in the way I first thought. That requires 4 separate files, not the same 2 twice. They are 4 separate recordings, LL, LR, RL & RR. It's similar to the way Altiverb works. I've had REVerance for years [since before it was released, as I used to beta test for Steinberg], but never really use it because I also have Altiverb & Waves IR. I now get the Fog concept too, it can take stereo files dropped to each pair of its 4 channels to produce the same thing as pre-combining to 4-channel wav. They still need to be different files.

Comment: They either consist of 4 separate files (better) or L-R-R-L (only slightly worse). Given the numerous stereo impulses stored on my hard drive I have no choice but to combine those and it actually does yields great results. So I'd be very grateful to learn how this can be done using ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 1):

The basic command syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i stereo_1.wav -af "asplit=2[a][b];[a][b]amerge=inputs=2" stereo_1_x2.wav
```

This will create a 4-channel stream.

`%~1` and `%~n1` are batch variables on Windows used as placeholders for substitution. The command processor (a.k.a. shell) will replace it with actual names during each iteration of the loop before sending the command to ffmpeg.

Comment: Your proposal basically works, thanks. Problem is that even though I'm getting the 4-channel output file, for some reason command prompt issues an error ("no channel layout for input one"). Due to it not figuring out the input channel layout, I can't use something like `asplit=2[a][b];[b][a]` to change the order of the channels as is probably needed for true-stereo.

Comment: Since both `[a]` and `[b]` are clones, there's no difference between the two order of inputs.

Comment: Is there a command that takes an L-R-type stereo input file and converts it to 4-channel with resulting channel order L-R-R-L?

Comment: `asplit=2[a][b];[b]channelmap=1|0[b];[a][b]amerge=inputs=2` or `pan=quad|c0=c0|c1=c1|c2=c1|c3=c0`

Comment: Your commands do seem to work! I'll do some testing ...

Comment: Both solutions work very well, thanks. Could you elaborate on the exact meaning of the asplit command in conjunction with mapping in this case? I don't get it. Also, would you mind having a look at my other ffmpeg-related thread (re-orderung audio channels in multichannel audio streams) since asplit may also help there.